# mongoengine calls causes django view to be called twice

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

when I create a new object it gets inserted into mongodb twice,
when I try to delete one, it does so and then try again only to tell me it couldn't find the object
it probably does the same thing on queries too tough it's not really a problem right now

I'm using django 1.4.1 with mongoengine 0.7.5

the code of my delete view is

```
def delbadge(request, oid):
    log.info('searching')
    try:
        badg = BgBadge.objects(id=oid)[0]
    except:
        log.error('not found')
        raise Http404
    badg.delete()
    log.info('deleted')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/badge/')
    #raise Http404
```

what it gives me is

```
searching
deleted
searching
not found
```

if I remove the `badg.delete()` I get

```
searching
deleted
```

same thing when I replace the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/badge/')` by `raise Http404`

So I tested the mongoengine code out of django and the django code without mongoengine and they both work just fine

edit:
the handler for `/badge/` is `url(r'^badge/$', AllBadges.as_view()),`
I checked the http requests and it doesn't appear to be the cause

update:
I tried on another computer and get the same behavior

Comment: Would it be possible to post the handler for the "/badge/" route?

Comment: Sounds like your handlers are executed twice. Otherwise you couldn't "searching" logged twice, correct?

Do be aware that MongoDB's remove() removes *all* matching documents, not just the first.

Comment: @jesse The fact that the problem comes from the handler or the view is irrelevant I think, since it disappears when the mongoengine call is removed. As for the MongoDB remove(), it is irrelevant too since I search for the object by oid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by django-debug-toolbar, more specifically the profiling panel whose hooks cause all views to be called twice.
Removing the `debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingDebugPanel` panel fixes the problem.
https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/267
The problem is known by the devs and is supposed to be fixed in the repos.